# php array_search key problem doesn't work in a for loop

Tags: php, arrays, function, for-loop

I'm having a hard time getting the key results from the for loop with the array_search in the php coding. As I've read in other postings the key result shows always the first result and discards the rest. If there's any other way that this would work let me know. What I need is to let the $getSearch array values be found in the $getKeyStrongs. And the rgb colors are connected with a :. So once it's found it would pick up the RGB color as well.

```html
<?php

$getKeyStrongs = isset($_GET["keystrongs"]) ? $_GET["keystrongs"] : "";
$getSearch = isset($_GET["search"]) ? $_GET["search"] : "";


$getsearcharray = explode("|", $getSearch);
$kwStrongsSplit = array_filter(explode("|", $getKeyStrongs));

$colstrongarray = array();
$strongarray = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($kwStrongsSplit);$i++){
    $kwStrongsColSplit = explode(":", $kwStrongsSplit[$i]);
    $keyStrongColor[] = str_replace("x", "rgb(", $kwStrongsColSplit[0]).")";
    $kwStrongsCommaSplit[] = explode(",", $kwStrongsColSplit[1]);
}

for($i=0;$i<count($keyStrongColor);$i++){
    $colstrongarray[] = ["color" => $keyStrongColor[$i], "strongs" => $kwStrongsCommaSplit[$i]];
}

$array = $colstrongarray;


$key = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($getsearcharray);$i++){
  for($j=0;$j<count($array);$j++){
 
    $key[] = array_search($getsearcharray[$i], $array[$j]["strongs"]);   
    if($key[$j]!=FALSE){
        echo "<span style=\"color: white; background-color:".$array[$j]["color"]."\">".$getsearcharray[$i]."</span> is in <span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">".$key[$j]."</span> and in j:".$j." and i is: ".$i."</br>\n";
    }
  }
}
echo "<pre>\n";
var_dump($array);
echo "</pre>\n";
echo "<pre>\n";
var_dump($key);
echo "</pre>\n";
?>
```

Comment: That's not valid syntax for creating an array., that's `var_dump()` output.

Comment: Yes it is var_dump. I put that in /**/. The array is hidden in the explode() result.

Comment: Could you post a simpler [mre]? It's hard to find the code in all that. Also show what the expected result is supposed to be.

Comment: I'd second what @Barmar wrote: it is nearly impossible in your code to say what is commented out and what not.

Comment: Here's the main code:
[php]
$key = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($getsearcharray);$i++){
  for($j=0;$j<count($array);$j++){
      $key[] = array_search($getsearcharray[$i], $array[$j]["strongs"]);   // $key = 1;
    if($key[$j]!=FALSE){
          echo "<span style=\"color: white; background-color:".$array[$j]["color"]."\">".$getsearcharray[$i]."</span> is in <span style=\"font-weight: bold;\">".$key[$j]."</span> and in j:".$j." and i is: ".$i."</br>\n";
    }
  }
}
[/php]

Comment: Any thoughts........?